# Common validation for multiple inputs MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

We have three input fileds(i.e Set1, Set2, and Set3) and each input have different max length properties:

- Set1 must be 3 digts long(only numeric).
- Set2 must be 3 digts long(only numeric).
- Set3 must be 6-9 digits long(only numeric).
  [image]

we can implement these mvc data annnotation validation on individual input. But we want common custom validator that will validate these inputs on both sides(server and client end) and shown the single message(i.e Sets are not valid).

Comment: That is not supported by by either any existing `ValidationAttribute`, or client side validation using `jquery.validate.js`. You would need to write you own server and client side code.

Comment: Could you please give any sample code?

Comment: No this is not duplicate of above given reference, here we have three inputs and one of them have different max length.

Comment: Yes it is a dupe, because it shows what you need to do. Create a custom `ValidationAttribute` that validates each of the properties in the `ValidationContext` and writes the error message to one of them (and you would do the same logic for the client side scripts that add the rules to the `$.validator`)

Comment: If you have a problem implementing it for your situation, then ask a new question with the code you have tried.

Comment: But frankly, writing a `ValidationAttribute` for a one-off is pointless. You may as well just remove you attributes, write the conditional code in the POST method to add a `ModelState` error, and write a script that handles the forms `.submit()` event that checks the values, and if not valid then cancel the submit and display an error message.